# Shortcut key to Skip all breakpoints in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, breakpoints, rad

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "`Skip All Breakpoints`" in eclipse?

If there isn't, is there a way to put "Skip all breakpoints" button on the tool bar in RAD like in eclipse? In eclipse it's there by default but I just couldn't figure out how to put it there in RAD.

I have been doing "Run" --> "Skip All BreakPoints" and this takes too much of my time when I am constantly enabling it and disabling it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to window -> Preference -> General -> Keys

Here in search box type "Remove All Breakpoints", if corresponding to that command if anything written in Binding option then it is your shortcut key, have a look on this pic

[image]

If nothing is mention then come to below given option [Binding] where you can add your own shortcut, i used Ctrl+Alt+B for removing all breakpoints. Then press Apply and ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the **Skip all Breakpoints** button show **on the toolbar panel.** You can do as fllow. Here is [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304505/6399074).

> 1. Go to **Window** > **Perspective** > **Customize Perspective**
> 2. Tick checkbox **Skip All Breakpoints** under **Debug** from **Tool Bar Visibility** as shown below
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Click on **OK**
> 4. You should see **Skip All Breakpoints** now

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse Mars (4.5)**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

[Here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M6/) is the official documentation for this new feature.