# "Skip All Breakpoints" disappeared from main toolbar

Tags: eclipse, customization, toolbar

As the title says, I already tried to readd the action under `Window` > `Customize Perspective...` with no success. The action is actually shown as visible in the dialog and removing and readding it also has no effect.

I tried to make it reappear by switching the perspectives but it seems the action disappeared from every single one.

Although I'm aware of the fact that the action can be found in the Breakpoints view I would be really happy if I could make it reappear in the main toolbar, since I'm so used to it.

Any ideas except reinstalling? Otherwise I'll have to bite the bullet.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I'm using Windows 7 64bit and Eclipse Kepler release for JavaEE with a custom perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Below changes worked for me..

1. Go to **Window** > **Perspective** > **Customize Perspective**
2. Tick checkbox **Skip All Breakpoints** under **Debug** from **Tool Bar Visibility** as shown below

[image]

3. Click on **OK**
4. You should see **Skip All Breakpoints** now

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below screen shot helps you. Skip All break points will appear only in the perspective in which you added to it. I also  assigned a keyboard short cut for it in `Windows > Preferences > General > Keys`.

[image]
Also check whether main toolbar is made visible or not. Check for the presence of **Hide Toolbar** menu item under **Windows** main menu. If instead of this if **Show Toolbar** menu item exists then click on it.

Edit you post if you are still facing this problem.

---

In Eclipse Standard Edition Kepler **SR2**(On Ubuntu 13.10) I am not able to enable **Skip All Breakpoints** option under **Breakpoints** node in **ToolBar Visibility** tab I am getting an error.

Try:

1. Switching to newer eclipse version(Old Workspace is compatible in new eclipse version)
2. Enable **Skip All Breakpoints** under **Debug** Node.

Comment: The main toolbar is visible and as I already explained in the question I tried to readd the item using the `Customize Perspective` menu. The item is considered visible there (it's checked) but it's still not visible in the toolbar. Removing and readding it didn't work either.

Comment: Which version of eclipse and OS are you using.

Comment: Windows 7 x64 and Eclipse Kepler Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Build id: Build id: 20130919-0819).

Comment: Name the perspective your are trying to customize?

Comment: It's a custom perspective. It used to work fine, until one day the item went on vacation.

Comment: But the item disappeared in the other perspectives too.

Comment: Stackoverflow NOT recommends prolong discussions in comments. Edit your question and mention all new problems and what you have tried so for.It also catches others attention.