# Eclipse Kepler Debugging Tools in main toolbar

Tags: eclipse, debugging, toolbar, perspective, eclipse-kepler

In **Eclipse `Juno`** I always had the debugging buttons in my own non-debugging view on the main toolbar. I have no idea if this was default or I did this somehow, but I can't seem to get them there in Eclipse **`Kepler`**.

I checked many debugging related boxes in the *Customize Perspective* dialog, but I am probably missing one, or missing something else.

I can open the `Debug window` into my perspective, go to the little triangle on the toolbar, and choose *"Show Debug Toolbar",* which shows the buttons I mean, but only on the `Debug window`. I want them on the main toolbar.

**In other words, my question is:**

### How do I do this?

[image]

No, I cannot drag and drop them. :/

---

Screenshots of `Customize Perspective`

**Tool Bar Visibility**
[image]

**Command Groups Availability**
[image: Command Groups Availability]

---

-update 2015-03-

Still not managed to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have these on main toolbar.
Steps

1. Switch to the perspective where you want to have these buttons(Ex: Java)
2. Click `Windows > Customize perspective`. Switch to **Commads and Groups Availability** tab. Enable **Debug** command group.
3. Switch to **Toolbar visibility** tab. Check **Debug** toolbar item.

### [image]

Refer this post ["Skip All Breakpoints" disappeared from main toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111801/skip-all-breakpoints-disappeared-from-main-toolbar/23191282#23191282) for screen shot [But not related to debug toolbar].

Comment: The options mentioned in step 2 and 3 are already enabled/checked. Still it is like in the screenshot, not on the main toolbar.

Comment: added my screen shot. I am using **eclipse luna** but should work on **kepler** also.Can you able to see these commands in **Toolbar visibility** tab. Edit your post and add screenshots

Comment: Hi __@ChandrayyaGK__, I'm revisiting this post to try again, but I still cannot manage. As you can see in the last screenshot from the updated question, I have no debug options on the main toolbar. I have __debug__ checked in both __Commads and Groups Availability__ and __Toolbar Visibility__. Any chance you missed mentioning a step?